# calculate probability from balls

Tags: algebra-precalculus

suppose that we have following problem:

[image]

i am interested if following problem could be solved using just number,suppose that we have $38$  red and $20$ green ball,so that total sum is $38+20=58$;now we know that  $2/7$ of this red ball,also have green color,so it means that $38*2/7=76/7$,which have red and also  green color,on the  other hand,we know that $3/7$ of green ball,also have red color,so that $20*3/7=60/7$  balls,which have  green color and also  red color,but as i know  if ball have  green and red color,then it is same yes which color would be first and which one second,or  red and  green or green and red,clearly  probability would be amount of balls which have both color divided by $58$.now let us calculate  how much  ball has not  both color,so  first $38-76/7=190/7$;

then $20-60/7=80/7$,

if we add $190/7+80/7=270/7$,which means that both color has $58-270/7=136/7$,

now if i divide $136/7$ by $58$,i will get

$136/406=0.33497536945812807881773399014778$

from book's answer is $6/29=0.20689655172413793103448275862069$

what is wrong?

also about answer,it is clear that $6/29=12/58$;

which means that there are $12$ ball that contain  red and green color,but how?

Comment: but actualy question   is about  proportion

Comment: this yes,unfortunately books  gave me this problem

Comment: only one thing i  want to know,2/7 multiplied  by only red number does equal 3/7 multiplied by only green number?

Comment: There are no fractional balls. 30 have red only, 16 have green only, 12 have both. $(2/7)(30+12)=(3/7)(16+12)$.

Comment: Oh, duh.  @GerryMyerson has the right method.  I goofed up and forgot to account for the "both" part in adding up the balls...  oops. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that there are $R$ purely red balls, $G$ purely green balls, and $M$ balls of mixed color. Thus
$$
R + G + M = 58.
$$
In total, $R+M$  are red, and $G+M$ are green, so
$$
\begin{align}
M &= \frac{2}{7}(R+M),\\
M &= \frac{3}{7}(G+M),
\end{align}
$$
which means that
$$
\begin{align}
R &= \frac{5}{2}M,\\
G &= \frac{4}{3}M,
\end{align}
$$
so we have
$$
\frac{5}{2}M + \frac{4}{3}M + M =58,
$$
and $M=12$. The probability to draw a mixed ball is thus $12/58$.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pick any pair of integers and assume they are the numbers of red and green balls just because their sum is 58.

The problem states that $2/7$ of the red balls are also green and $3/7$ of the green balls are also red. Since one green-red ball is the same as a red-green ball we must have, assuming that $g$ is the number of green balls, $r$ the number or red balls and rg the number of red-green balls.

$$rg=\frac{2r}{7}=\frac{3g}{7}$$

Solving this equation we have that

$$r=1.5g$$

We also know that the sum of the balls must equal to 58.

$$(r-rg)+(g-rg)+rg=58$$ Note that I subtracted $rg$ to only account for the number of solid color balls.

$$1.5g +g -\frac{3g}{7}=58$$

$$g=28$$

Finally $$rg=\frac{3g}{7}=12$$

The probability to draw a mixed color ball will be $\frac{12}{58}$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be the following:

Let $r$ be the number of balls colored (at least) in red, and let $g$ be the number of balls colored (at least) in green. There is a certain number of red balls that are colored also in green: they are: $\frac{2}{7}r$.
The number of green balls colored also in red are: $\frac{3}{7}g$.
We found two expressions for the number of balls that are both red and green. Equating the expressions we get:
$$\frac{2}{7}r=\frac{3}{7}g $$
$$r=\frac{3}{2}g $$
We didn't use that the total number of balls is $58$ and by the principle of inclusion-exclusion we know that the total number of ball is given by the number of red balls plus the number of green balls minus the number of balls that are both red and green. Hence we get:
$$58=r+g-\frac{3}{7}g$$
$$58=\frac{3}{2}g+g-\frac{3}{7}g$$
$$58=g\left(\frac{3}{2}+1-\frac{3}{7}\right)$$

$$58=g\frac{29}{14}$$
$$g=28$$
Therefore we get: $r=42$ and the number of balls that are both red and green is $\frac{3}{7}g =12 $

The requested probability is $$\frac{12}{58}=\frac{6}{29}$$

Your mistake is that taking 38 red balls and 20 green you can't have any ball that has both the colors. In fact the set of the green ball has to be disjoint with the set of the red ones. In order to have a few balls that are both red and green you need to have $r+g>58$

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the following events:\begin{align}
G:& \mbox{A ball has green color on it}\\
R:& \mbox{A ball has red color on it}\\
\end{align}

According to the question $$P(R\cup G)=1$$ since each ball has at least one color on it. Now, according to the given conditions, $$P(R\cap G|R)=\frac{2}{7}\\
P(R \cap G|G)=\frac{3}{7}$$ Let $$x:=P(R\cap G)$$

Then, it follows that $$P(R)=\frac{7}{2}x\\
\Rightarrow P(G)=\frac{7}{3}x$$ Then,
we have $$P(R \cup G)=P(R)+P(G)-P(R\cap G)\\
\Rightarrow 1=\frac{7}{2}x+\frac{7}{3}x-x\\ \Rightarrow x=\frac{6}{29}$$